# how to set grid's column dataindex like depart.name

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I have two classes

```
public class Employee
{
    int id;
    String name;
    Depart depart;
}

public class Depart
{
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

so i query the employee data back to the extjs like

```
{total:2,list:[{"id":1,,"name":"jack",depart:{"id":1,"name":"departA"},{"id":2,,"name":"rose",depart:{"id":2,"name":"departB"}}
```

i set model like

```
{
    ....

    {
        type: 'string',
        name: 'depart.name'
    }    

    ....
}
```

in the grid's column,i set like this

```
{
    ...
    dataIndex: 'depart.name',
    ...
}
```

but the grid's column can't show the depart's name, how to do?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [mapping](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-mapping).

```
fields: [
    { name: 'depart_name', type: 'string', mapping: 'depart.name'}
]
```

In the grid's column:

```
{
    ...
    dataIndex: 'depart_name',
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use renderer function.

```
dataIndex : "anything",
renderer  : function (val,record) {
     return record.data.depart.name;
}
```